# Monotouch memory leak

Tags: memory, xamarin.ios, memory-leaks

A variation of the code below used to work, but now I get a memory leak as you can see in the screenshot below.  I moved the code from a different thread to a TimerElapsed event (see stack trace in screenshot), made various code updates and upgrades to MD 3.0.3.4 and MT 5.3.4.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work anymore.  Reverting to a previous version of code where it's being called from a regular thread doesn't seem to work either.  Is this a bug in the current version of MD or MT?

As you can see, I'm using NSAutoReleasePool as well as forcing a garbage collect at the end and it still doesn't work!

**EDIT:** I've added code below that traces the unpackedImage from its declaration through DrawCustomImage, then into SetImages() as the "imageToSet" parameter, then into overlayImage() as the "overlay" parameter.  SetImage invokes the code inside it on the main thread because when it eventually calls UpdateLiveScreen (with the resulting overlayedImage), it actually draws to the screen.

```
    static UIImage unpackedImage = new UIImage();

    public static void DrawCustomImage(IntPtr buffer, int width, int height, int bytesPerRow, CGColorSpace colSpace, byte[] rawPixels, ref UIImage unpackedImage)
    {
        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
        {
            GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(rawPixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            // Set a grayscale drawing context using the image buffer
            CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(pointer, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.None);

            try
            {
                // Convert the drawing context to an image and set it as the unpacked image
                //using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
                {
                    using (var img = context.ToImage())
                    {
                        unpackedImage = UIImage.FromImage(img);
                    }
                }
            } finally
            {
                pinnedArray.Free();
                if (context != null)
                    context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }

    SetImages(labelText, symbolArray[0], unpackedImage, points);

    public static void SetImages(String labelText, UIImage symbol, UIImage imageToSet, PointF[] points)
    {
        appReference.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
        {
            int imageWidth = 716;
            int imageHeight = (int)imageToSet.Size.Height;
                            int nextFreeMainImageColumn = 5; // This gets set dynamically, but is simplified here for readability 

            lock (displayLocker)
            {
                // Get the current doppler image
                UIImage mainImage = GetMainImage();

                // Add the new imageToSet to the current image by overlaying it adjacent to the current image
                UIImage overlayedImage = overlayImage(mainImage, imageToSet,
                                     new RectangleF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight),
                                     new RectangleF(nextFreeMainImageColumn, 0, imageToSet.Size.Width, imageHeight));

                // Update the live screen with the updated image and frame number
                LiveCont.UpdateLiveScreen(labelText, symbol, overlayedImage, points);
            }
        });
    }

    public static UIImage overlayImage(UIImage image, UIImage overlay, RectangleF imageBoundingBox, RectangleF overlayBoundingBox)
    {
        int numBytes = 4;   // Four bytes per pixel for a color image (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
        int bytesPerRow = (int)imageBoundingBox.Width * numBytes;

        // Set a color drawing context
        CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (int)imageBoundingBox.Width,
            (int)imageBoundingBox.Height,
            8,
            bytesPerRow,
            CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(),
            CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst
        );

        UIImage overlayedImage = null;
        try
        {
            context.DrawImage(imageBoundingBox, image.CGImage);             // Draw the main image
            context.DrawImage(overlayBoundingBox, overlay.CGImage);         // Draw the overlay

            using (var img = context.ToImage())
            {
                overlayedImage = UIImage.FromImage(img);                    // Convert the context back to an image
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (context != null)
                context.Dispose();
            image.Dispose();
        }

        return overlayedImage;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I reverted to MT 5.2.12 and the issue went away, so there must be some bug in the MT code between MT 5.2.12 and 5.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for filling a [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6227).

The native call to `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` (from the Instruments' stack trace) is being done when your call `ToImage` (see [source](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreGraphics/CGBitmapContext.cs)). That code has not changed between 5.2.12 and 5.3 so it's likely not the culprit.

The *managed* `GCImage` does not take an extra reference to the handle (`true` is used in the .ctor) (see [source](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreGraphics/CGImage.cs), no recent change either).

So this takes us to the `unpackedImage` `UIImage` that you return from your method. There's a change (in 5.3.x) where an *automatic* `NSAutoreleasePool` is used around this call.

Otherwise it ends up in where/how you deal with the returned `unpackedImage` (and on which thread, e.g. CoreGraphics is thread-safe while UIKit *mostly* is not).

Could you add the code (here or privately on the bug report) showing this ? I don't believe the issue is with your code (since it works on 5.2.x) but it would make tracking this a lot easier.

Note that calling `GC.Collect` is not helpful (and it's rarely is) since the instances you're using all implement `IDisposable` (which *generally* immediately dispose of the resources and remove the finalization step) and you dispose them manually or with `using`.